# Angular wildcard route replacing child routes

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application, angular7, angular7-router

I have a module called "host" with its own routing that I want to insert into the app-routing.module. However, I have the problem of the wildcard loading first and displaying PageNotFoundComponent, instead of the Host component loading. I have the following files.

**host.module.ts**

```
....
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'host',
    children: [
     { path: '', component: HostComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HostComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class HostModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full"},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HostModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>Home</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a routerLink="/host">host</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Problem:** When I run the app and click on the "Host" button, it loads the PageNotFoundComponent. I obviously want it to go to the HostComponent.

[image]

Comment: Expected result? I don't see you have a route path for 'host' or it's lazy loaded.

Comment: @penleychan please see my update in the original question. There is a routerLink for Host in the app.component.html

Comment: Again, where and how `HostModule` is being used/defined. If you are just importing the module to `AppModule` you need to manage your import order. The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design.

Comment: @penleychan Oh, i think i see what you're asking. I updated with the app.module.ts file. Please see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` you need to reorder your imports

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HostModule, <--- this before AppRoutingModule
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Reason being is because the order of the routes in the configuration matters.  https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

> The ** path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.
>
> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Comment: Is this something new that's in Angular 7? I don't remember this being like this for other versions. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @user1142130 No, pretty sure it has always been like this, perhaps previously you were doing lazy loading?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just spent 4 hours trying to solve this problem. Frustrating.